# IE6 Try/Catch block does not work on custom document.someFunction call

Tags: javascript, try-catch, document, internet-explorer-6

How can I attach a function to the global document object in IE6, and still be able to catch exceptions thrown from that function when called?

Surprisingly, the exception does not propagate outside the function in IE6 in example below:

```js
// Declare function on document
document.someFn = function()
{
    throw new Error('Raised error');
}

// IE6: bug??
try{
    document.someFn('some parameter');
    alert('2. error has not been raised: bad!');
}
catch(err) {
}
```

You can try out the example and some extra test cases here:

http://www.pokret.org/stuff/ie6-bug-test.html

Any workaround ideas?

Comment: Why are you even trying to attaching function to document object ?!

Comment: It does seem crazy, but according to [DOM XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-XPath/xpath.html#XPathEvaluator), **createExpression** and other functions must be made available on the **document** object in order to conform with the said standard.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a monumentally old question, but just in case someone comes along after me running into the same problem, I've found that this seems to work:

```
// Declare function on document
document.someFn = function() {
  throw new Error('Raised error');
}

try {
  document.someFn.apply(null, 'some parameter');
  alert('2. error has not been raised: bad!');
}
catch(err) {
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did something like that, but it would be more appropriate to pass "document" into apply(), rather then "null".

Answer (score -1):

```
function someFn ( txt ) {
    throw new Error( 'Raised error: ' + txt );
}

try {
    someFn( 'im dead' );
    alert( 'im alive' ); // will not be shown
} catch(err) {
    if( 'description' in err ) {
        alert( err.description ); // IE
    } else {
        alert( err ); // other browsers
    }

}
```

MSDN article on [try...catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yahc5d8%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) in IE.

Comment: Not my downvote, but I see why you got it. The OP wants to attach `someFn` to `document`. You didn't, hence it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: tnx.. but as you can read from code comment - he is **declaring a function** - so i assumed, he is just doing it wrong, and ignored.

Comment: I downvoted because try/catch has nothing to do with standards/quirks mode

Comment: Not bad ) This was indeed my mistake, yet it was a _notice_, which does not relate much to code shown.